# Jquery Validation Engine with datepicker not works on server, but works in local

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-validation-engine

I use **Validation Engine** in user register form. When enter `Birthday` I use **date picker**. Validation is binded to blur event. that is why when calendar opens and I select year, message appears. To fix this I used:

```
@class = "validate[required] text-input datepicker"
```

according documentation. For datepicker I use:

```
$("#BirthDay").datepicker();
```

Problem is that, in local this works, but I deploy site to hosting, it working only in second time.

I select `Birthday` from calendar, always **01/01/0001 00:00:00** value sending to server in first time, but I try second time, change date from calendar then it works right, send selected date.
I can not understand it's reason..Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging.  [tag:jquery-validate] and [tag:jquery-validation-engine] are two different plugins.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my self found my solution. I took this line from config it worked:

```
<globalization culture="en-gb"/>
```